# Python re to split dates from other data

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This shouldn't be too hard but for some reason I can't figure out how to do this.
I have a date followed by some data, it's all the same string, like:

`2015-11-27 A1,B3`
`2015-11-23 A1`
`2015-11-22 A1,B3,Z6`

Right now I'm trying to do `re.compile(r'^(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d) (\w\d)(,\w\d)?(,\w\d)?')`
And that works, but if there's less than three character/digit pairs it returns an empty string or two.
Is there a way I can compress the compile to be more efficient It just feels too brute force for me.

Comment: Why don't you just use a vanilla `str.split`? Split once on whitespace then split the second resulting element on commas.

Comment: I suppose you two are right. I was just trying to learn how to use regex. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, I guess:

```
import re

string = """2015-11-27 A1,B3
2015-11-23 A1
2015-11-22 A1,B3,Z6"""

for line in re.split("\n", string):
    date, rest = re.split("\s", line)
    print "Date: " + date + ", Rest: " + rest

    #parts = re.split(",", rest)
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ZaXygV). Obviously, there is not really a regex engine needed unless you may have commas in `A`, `B3` or `Z6` as well (please be more precise on your strings in this case).